# Creating custom viewlets for RTC dashborads

Tags: rtc

I am new to RTC customization and want to know how do we create custom viewlets for dashboard and deploy them onto the server.

I have looked at the `helloWorldViewlet` tutorial but it does not makes me clear on how to actually deploy it on server.

What would b the right procedure to deploy a viewlet on RTC?

Answer (score 0):

More references are available at "[ViewletAuthoring](https://jazz.net/wiki/bin/view/Main/ViewletAuthoring)" (which seems to be [*still* the most up-to-date version](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/31346/developing-custom-viewlet-to-show-remote-web-content/31348))

The [`DashboardHelloWorldViewlet`](https://jazz.net/wiki/bin/view/Main/DashboardHelloWorldViewlet) tutorial shows how to run/deploy the viewlet on a local test server, so deploying it on the actual Jazz server should be fairly similar and involve registering it:

> how does the dashboard know about the viewlet? It has to be registered as an extension. If you open the plug-in manifest (`plugin.xml`)